# Regex in Rack-Rewrite redirecting more than it should

Tags: ruby, regex, rack-rewrite

I have a redirect setup like so:

```
r302 %r{(/example/.*)}i, 'http://new-domain.com/$1'
```

For this URL `http://example.com/example` it works great redirecting to `http://new-domain.com/example`

I would like to adapt this regex *(or expression)* to not redirect if the URL has more than one level of directory, such as `http://example.com/admin/example`

Comment: If `http://example.com/example` Then redirect to => `http://new-domain.com/example`? And if `http://example.com/admin/example` Don't redirect. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically we simply anchor the start of the string with `^`. which matches at the start of a string and is zero-width:

```
r302 %r{^(/example/.*)}i, 'http://new-domain.com/$1'
```

Comment: @Neil, which was it, the first or the second? I'll edit my answer to only display the correct one for future peoples.

Comment: The first option...Thanks!!